# Python exe user input auto enter

Tags: python, operating-system, exe

Hi i have a short python script that receives an input (file path) and then rename the file.

I have converted my python script to an executable.

My problem is that after the user enter then input the executable will not run until the user will

press enter.

How can i make the exe run without waiting for the enter to be pressed/ or make that enter auto pressed?

Here is my code :

```
import os

dir = os.getcwd()
input = input() 
end = ('.xml.xml')
for file in os.listdir(dir):
 file_path  = (dir+'\\'+file)
 if file_path == input:
    os.rename(dir+'\\'+file,dir+'\\'+file+end)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to provide more information, especially a minimal code example producing the issue.

Comment: I have added my code - it is very simple- just renaming a file

Comment: How do you want the program to understand the user has finished typing the input without pressing enter? Are you trying to use command line arguments?

Comment: Hi, the input will be inserted by another program (our ERP system) - i thought maybe i can use time.sleep - 10 seconds to type the input and afterwards to press enter, whether an input has been inserted or not